# How to disable code coverage for lambda function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

As the title suggested, lambda functions (even those declared local to a function) seems to be detected as normal functions, thus not testing it will decrease code coverage.

I use Visual Studio 2013 Native Unit Test library with C++.

Is there a quick way to exclude a particular blocks of code to be analysed?